# Geting details of contents from a remote server in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, cfnetwork

I am working on an app where I need to get details(file name, size, modified date) of contents of a directory from remote server. I will be having the url of the directory e.g, http://www.mywebsite.com/myfolder.

I have checked FTPSample code, but it is for ftp only, and I want to do it via http.

Answer (score 0):

This grabs content from a file and puts it into NSData

```
NSString *str=@"http://your_web_server/your_file....";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error=nil;
    id *response=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:
                            NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error]; 

NSLog("Your JSON Object: %@ Or Error is: %@, response, error);
```

Basically the: `initWithContentsOfURL` or `dataWithContentsOfURL` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I dont have any json/xml web service. I need details of content of the folder from the url.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just use HTTP to access the url if your web site allow web browse action from public online user, but as I know a good web site not allow online user do this way, so, you have to write a web service or just a PHP code file that got file list from the directory and return file information as xml response (or json as you like), then your iOS app can got the xml and parse it to got the file information, this should be best solution to your site if you want the site stable